# How to upload document whenever a user signs up in firebase with custom users uid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working with react and firebase ver 9. As firebase offers limited field and I need to send some more data while registering a user. I saw that you can do this while uploading document whenever a user signs up. I have written the code for it but when I run it only users are registered but my document doesn`t get uploaded.

Here`s my code:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { auth, db } from "../Authentication/firebaseConfig"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import {

    collection,
    setDoc,
    addDoc,doc
} from "firebase/firestore";


export const useSignup = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)


    const signup = async (email, password, displayName) => {
        setError(null)

        const current_user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password, displayName);
        const uid = current_user.user.uid;
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
            uid: uid,
            displayName,
            email,
        })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('user signed up:', res.user)
        })
    .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message)
    })
       
        
    }
    return { error, signup }
}
```

Comment: At a glance, there should be no issue on adding a document to your `users` collection. What I just notice is the `res.user` which will definitely return undefined as documents don't have `user` property but should still add documents to the collection. Could you change it to `res.id` so that it will print the document id instead. Have you checked your Firestore console if there's no added document on the users collection? And lastly, does your code produce an error when trying to run the function? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing database rules from false to true. I searched StackOverflow for the answers but many people had the same issue regarding uploading documents on user signup but there was no proper solution.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer so that it can also help the community.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @Danial, the error was produced by Cloud Firestore Rules that is set to `false`.

Sample Rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Sample Firestore rule above will prohibit you to read and write to any collection and document. Changing it to `true` allows the public to read and write to Firestore.